# Why is text-align formatting only applied to first line within tag

Tags: html, css

In the html/css code below, I am trying to get apply the same text indentation to multiple lines within the `<p>` tag via the `.code-box` class using `text-indent`. However, only the 1st line ("code line 1") is successfully applying the text indentation.

Why? How do I fix this?

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            .code-box {
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
                text-indent: 50px;
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Some big title</h1>
        <div>
            Some text explain the code below
            <p class="code-box">
                <code>
                    code line 1
                    <br />
                    code line 2 - why isn't this text indented like code line 1
                    <br />
                    code line 3 - same question
                </code>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you're seeing is `text-indent`, not `text-align`.

Comment: You're actually seeing both, but the text-indent property specifies the indentation of the first line in a text-block. Use padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-indent` only affects the first line of a paragraph, if you need indentations for all lines, why not just try `padding`?

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            .code-box {
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
                /* use padding instead of text-indent */
                padding-inline-start: 50px;
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Some big title</h1>
        <div>
            Some text explain the code below
            <p class="code-box">
                <code>
                    code line 1
                    <br />
                    code line 2 - why isn't this text indented like code line 1
                    <br />
                    code line 3 - same question
                </code>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```